# How to be calm and relaxed during a performance, recital, or competition?

Tags: piano, performing, stage-fright

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to overcome audience fear?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/how-to-overcome-audience-fear)

I play the piano and have to frequently perform on stage, and participate in competitions. Sometimes, I remain calm and played well. However, at times, I also do feel nervous, and this resulted to me playing badly for the performance or competition. What do you think I should do before the performance to keep myself calm?