# How to come over nervousness while stage performance?

Tags: theory, performing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I overcome the fear of performing in front of an audience?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/how-can-i-overcome-the-fear-of-performing-in-front-of-an-audience)

I have played guitar several time on stage. But every time I start performing I feel a lot nervous. I may call it stage fear but I want to defeat this feeling now. Please let me know what I can do or make myself comfortable while playing music on stage.

(It only happens when I am playing music on stage. It never really happened while giving a presentation in office. :P)

Comment: Related: http://music.stackexchange.com/q/505/249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind is that you should know it is not the end of the world if you do mistakes. Most mistakes that you do will not even be noticed by the audience, even if you think it's a big mistake.

Because of this, you must continue as nothing happened.

Knowing this fact, you can also have more confidence, because you will know that it is not important to play 100% perfect (or 83% perfect). Even if you do mistakes that are so obvious that the audience will notice, it will be no issue if you just ignore it yourself.

If you make faces or stop and comment it or something, the audience will most likely remember the mistake after the performance, but if you ignore it and just play on, the audience will have forgot it after 32 seconds (more or less...).